# set folder wise default page in web application

Tags: asp.net, iis

How to set default page folder wise in asp.net web application

I have used IIS for setting default  page. But It is for the setting default page for web application, not folder wise.

I need default page folder wise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific file to be used per each folder then this SO question should work:

[Setting folder default page in aspnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768517/setting-folder-default-page-in-aspnet)